# How to stop airodump-ng with the Python subprocess module

Tags: python

I wrote a program (I ran it in the terminal) that goes through a list of terminal commands (Kali).

```
import subprocess as sub
import time
sub.call(['airmon-ng', 'start', 'wlan0'])
p = sub.call(['airodump-ng','wlan0mon'])
time.sleep(10)
p.kill()
```

The last commmand is `airodump-ng wlan0mon`. Everything works fine (everything is displayed in the terminal (beacons, ESSID, etc.)).

After a specified time I wish to kill the process (`airodump-ng wlan0mon`).

I dont want to press `ctrl-c` by hand!
`p.kill()` does not work (maybe improper use)

How can I do this? What command to send through the subprocess module?

Comment: While your program is about airodump, I think the question isn't really security related.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call()` waits for the subprocess to finish before your Python program executes the next statement.  You'll want to use `subprocess.Popen()` to initialize a separate ("background") process and then continue your Python program.

```
sub.call(['airmon-ng', 'start', 'wlan0'])
p = sub.Popen(['airodump-ng','wlan0mon'])
time.sleep(10)
p.kill()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use subprocess to run "killall airodump-ng".

However, if you do this, you may as well convert the whole thing to a bash script.